# Get semantic object and semantic action in controller

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm trying to get the semantic object and semantic action of my deployed SAPUI5 application. I tried looking into ushell services - URLParsing and LaunchPage but it does not seem to return my semantic objects and actions.

Have anybody tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just use

```
window.location.hash
```

Which you can parse yourself pretty easily. If you really want launchpad code, you can often find it here:

```
sap.ushell.services.AppConfiguration.getCurrentApplication().sShellHash
```

I've noticed it's not always set though when you're looking at an embedded component

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me so far:

```js
sap.ui.require([ // modules lazily instead of accessing them with global names.
  "sap/ushell/library", // Consider adding `"sap.ushell": { lazy: true }` to dependencies in manifest.json
  "sap/ui/core/routing/HashChanger",
], async (sapUshellLib, HashChanger) => {
  const fullHash = new HashChanger().getHash(); // returns e.g. "masterDetail-display?sap-ui-theme=sap_fiori_3&/product/HT-1000"
  const urlParsing = await sapUshellLib.Container.getServiceAsync("URLParsing");
  urlParsing.parseShellHash(fullHash); /** returns e.g. {
    action: "display",
    appSpecificRoute: "&/product/HT-1000",
    contextRaw: undefined,
    params: { "sap-ui-theme": "sap_fiori_3" },
    semanticObject: "masterDetail"
  } **/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic way to do this would be:

```js
var oHashObject = new sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger();
oHashObject.getHash();  

//this will return the semantic object and action alongwith the routing params
```